# Special symbols are missed in name of file uploaded using Google Sites API

Tags: google-api, google-sites

**The goal:** I want to upload file to my Google Classic Site programmatically using [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol).

**Used approach:** To create a file in my Google Classic Site I use [this request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#UploadingFiles) with

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=END_OF_PART
```

header and request body like this:

```
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
            term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#attachment" label="attachment" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#parent" type="application/atom+xml"
            href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainName/siteName/PARENT_ENTRY_ID"/>
  <title>File Title</title>
  <summary />
  <content type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
  </content>
  ...
  <-- Other matadata here -->
</entry>


--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: <file mime type here>

... file contents here ...

--END_OF_PART--
```

**The problem:** When File Title starts with symbols like '_' (underscore), '%' (percent sign), '*' (asterisk), '&' (ampersand) request is successfully executed and file on my Google Classic Site in created with right content but with different title - no symbols listed above at the beginning of file name.

Is this known issue in [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#UploadingFiles)? What I do wrong? How can I handle this problem?

Comment: A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. The Sites API cannot access or modify Sites made with this version, but can still access classic Sites.

Comment: For me it looks like there is only [this public Google API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/) for working with Google Sites (and only with Classic Sites).